# WooCommerce: separate login page and registration page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use the WooCommerce plugin 2.0.13. On my account page there are login and register sections, both on the same page. I want them separate.

I edit `form_login.php` to create two files: `form_login.php` for login and `form_register.php` for registration.

In the new `form_login.php` I provide a link to `form_registration.php` as follows:

```
<a href="' .get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')). '?action=register"> register </a>
```

In my theme's `function.php` file, I added the following code.

```
/*//  Separate login form and registration form */
add_action('woocommerce_before_my_account', 'load_registration_form', 2);
function load_registration_form() {
    if (isset($_GET['action']) == 'register') {
        woocommerce_get_template('myaccount/form-registration.php');
    }
}
```

But this doesn’t work. What's going wrong? Is what I am doing completely wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a copy of the WooCommerce `form-login.php` and name it `form-register.php`. The `form-login.php` is located in `/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/` folder.

Then in the `form-login.php` you can create a link to the form-register.php using this code:

```
<a href="' .get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')). '?action=register"> register </a>
```

Next you need to modify your themes `function.php` file by adding the following code:

```
<?php
    /* Separate login form and registration form */
    add_action('woocommerce_before_customer_login_form', 'load_registration_form', 2);
    function load_registration_form() {
      if (isset($_GET['action']) == 'register') {
        woocommerce_get_template('myaccount/form-registration.php');
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/* shortcode for Register */
add_shortcode( 'wc_reg_form', 'registration_form' );
            
        function registration_form() {
           if ( is_admin() ) return;
           if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return;
           ob_start();
         
           
           
         
           do_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form' );
         
           ?>
              <form method="post" class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-register register" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_tag' ); ?> >
         
                 <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start' ); ?>
         
                 <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ) : ?>
         
                    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                       <label for="reg_username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                       <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="reg_username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
                    </p>
         
                 <?php endif; ?>
         
                 <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="reg_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" />
                 </p>
         
                 <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ) : ?>
         
                    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                       <label for="reg_password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                       <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" autocomplete="new-password" />
                    </p>
         
                 <?php else : ?>
         
                    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'A password will be sent to your email address.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
         
                 <?php endif; ?>
         
                 <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form' ); ?>
         
                 <p class="woocommerce-FormRow form-row">
                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce' ); ?>
                    <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-register__submit" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
                 </p>
         
                 <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_end' ); ?>
         
              </form>
         
           <?php
             
           return ob_get_clean();
        }
    /* login shortcode */
    add_shortcode( 'wc_login_form', 'login_form' );
      
    function login_form() {
       if ( is_admin() ) return;
       if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return; 
       ob_start();
       woocommerce_login_form( array( 'redirect' => 'https://custom.url' ) );
       return ob_get_clean();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You created a file named **form_register.php** and you are calling **form_registration.php**. This is the main  issue.

The method woocommerce_get_template is also outdated now, use wc_get_template instead.

After making a copy of your form-login.php, make sure to comment this line in form-register.php:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form' );
```

Otherwise you will be inside an infinite loop using the filter woocommerce_before_customer_login_form.

Answer (score 0):

The hook that you are using is wrong. It won't be executed as the user is not logged in.

You should be using `woocommerce_before_customer_login_form`.