# Suggestions to create separate login and registration WooCommerce pages still do not work

Tags: woocommerce

I know this question has been asked a gazillion times and surprising enough all of the suggested answers still do not work till this day.

I wanted to make one last-ditch effort to reach out to see if anyone has a solid solution to create a separate login and registration page in WooCommerce before I give up on the platform all together. It is extremely frustrating that something that should be simple appears to be so challenging.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, could you clarify why other solutions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649049/woocommerce-separate-login-page-and-registration-page?rq=1 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821488/separate-registration-page-in-woocommerce-website?rq=1 does not work?

Comment: By documenting your research in the question itself, not here in comments.

Comment: Please elaborate on *"still do not work"*. What are the symptoms? What platform and versions was it tried on?

Comment: I would recommend creating an HTML form for login and upon submitting the form, you can use the in-built Wordpress function (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_signon/) to login the user. I understand that my comment has got to do less with Woocommerce. Please mention where in Woocommerce do you want to create the Login and Registration form?

Comment: Hello I tried the recommended solutions highlighted in the follow thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649049/woocommerce-separate-login-page-and-registration-page?rq=1 and they do not. The result is a page not found 404 page error.